# How to report a bug in Mathematica

Tags: debugging

I found two bugs in Mathematica (10.3 and 10.1) and I need to report it. Is there any tools to do that or section on Wolfram website?

Comment: email support@wolfram.com.

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks so much

Comment: Or fill out the online [form](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can contact Wolfram Tech Support through this form:

- http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback

or by sending an email to

- `support@wolfram.com`

**Please always report bugs you find to Wolfram Technical Support.**

Some people will post bugs to this StackExchange site. Please do not do this. It is okay to ask about workarounds to bugs here, and it is also okay to ask if a particular behaviour is likely a bug. **But do not use StackExchange for *reporting* bugs.**  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com does not belong to Wolfram research, and Wolfram may never find out about bugs reported only here.  It is in all Mathematica users' interest to get bugs fixed.  To ensure that this can happen, Wolfram should be notified *directly* about any bugs you find.

Comment: Here're more up-to-date guidelines for dealing with Mathematica bugs: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2317/61342

Comment: The last few times I tried, after filling in the linked feedback form, I got an error message about a server error. If you don't want your feedback to disappear I suggest using the email instead.