# Why cannot I label a date point using TimelinePlot with Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, version-11.3

I have tried to simplify this issue as much as I can at the moment: it looks like a bug to me but perhaps I've missed something obvious.

I am trying to build an interactive scheduler using `TimelinePlot` and I find that the following code reports that I've tried to plot an invalid dataset:

```
Manipulate[Column@{DatePlus[{2019, 1, 15}, sdate],
TimelinePlot[{{Labeled[{2011, 1, 1}, "hello"], {2012, 1, 1}, {2013, 1, 1}}, 
    {Labeled[Interval[{{2011, 3, 1}, {2012, 7, 7}}], mylabel], 
     Interval[{{2012, 9, 12}, {2013, 12, 21}}]}, {Labeled[
     Interval[{DatePlus[{2011, 3, 1}, sdate], 
     DatePlus[{2012, 7, 7}, sdate]}], "Moving interval"], 
     Labeled[Interval[{{2012, 9, 12}, {2013, 12, 21}}], "Range"]}}]}, 
  {sdate, 0, 200, 1}, 
  {mylabel, {"la", "lb", "lc"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but this works fine

```
Manipulate[Column@{DatePlus[{2019, 1, 15}, sdate],
TimelinePlot[{{{2011, 1, 1}, {2012, 1, 1}, {2013, 1, 1}}, 
{Labeled[
   Interval[{{2011, 3, 1}, {2012, 7, 7}}], mylabel], 
   Interval[{{2012, 9, 12}, {2013, 12, 21}}]}, 
{Labeled[
   Interval[{DatePlus[{2011, 3, 1}, sdate], 
     DatePlus[{2012, 7, 7}, sdate]}], "Moving interval"], 
   Labeled[Interval[{{2012, 9, 12}, {2013, 12, 21}}], 
   "Range"]}}]}, {sdate, 0, 200, 1}, 
{mylabel, {"la", "lb", "lc"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

as well as this:

```
With[{sdate = 1, mylabel = "foo"},
 Column@{DatePlus[{2019, 1, 15}, sdate],
 TimelinePlot[{{Labeled[{2011, 1, 1}, "hello"], {2012, 1, 1}, {2013,
    1, 1}}, {Labeled[Interval[{{2011, 3, 1}, {2012, 7, 7}}], 
   mylabel], 
  Interval[{{2012, 9, 12}, {2013, 12, 21}}]}, {Labeled[
   Interval[{DatePlus[{2011, 3, 1}, sdate], 
     DatePlus[{2012, 7, 7}, sdate]}], "Moving interval"], 
  Labeled[Interval[{{2012, 9, 12}, {2013, 12, 21}}], "Range"]}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Two smaller examples exhibiting two aspects of the issue:

(1) `TimelinePlot[{{Labeled[{2011, 3, 1}, "Label"]}}]` works as expected but `Manipulate[TimelinePlot[{{Labeled[{2011, 3, 1}, "Label"]}}], {sdate, 0, 200, 1}]` gives an error.

(2) Although `TimelinePlot[{{{2011, 3, 1}, Interval[{{2011, 3, 1}, DatePlus[{2011, 3, 1}, 100]}]}}]` works fine, inside `Manipulate` it gives an error message. In general, if any element of `datai` in `TimeLinePlot[{data1, ..., datan}]` is a date list (`{y,m,d,...}`)  without wrappers all elements of `datai` should be date lists without wrappers.

**A work-around:**  Wrap the date lists with `DateObject` (or `DateList` or `AbsoluteTime`), that is, use

```
{Labeled[DateObject@{2011, 1, 1}, "hello"], DateObject@{2012, 1, 1}, DateObject@{2013, 1, 1}}
```

in the first sublist of your input data to get

[image]

Comment: yes, that seems to fix it thanks

Comment: just waiting to see if it is confirmed as a bug and if that's the best workaround.

Comment: well, I haven't asked via the official route if it's a bug; it could be called a design choice but I prefer to mark it as a bug.  Only I'm not quite sure how to do that, I'll have to find out what the standard bug headers are...

Comment: @fairflow, please see [How to report a bug in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106227/125).

Comment: yes @kglr thanks for the prompt; but actually I wanted to know how to add a bug tag to a question and the advice is not just to add the tag bug but to use the "standard bug headers" instead and I didn't know what that meant.