# Resolve Error or Mathematica's Bug?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, resolve

The following code,

```
    Resolve[Exists[{n1, n2, n3}, {n1, n2, n3} \[Element] 
   NonNegativeIntegers, 
  1/2 (1 + n1 + n2 - n3) \[Element] NonPositiveIntegers]]
```

gives output `True` but if I run `LaunchKernels[]` and then rerun the exact same code above then  the output is

```
Exists[{n1, n2, n3}, Element[n1 | n2 | n3, Integers] && 
  n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0 && n3 >= 0, 
 Element[(1 + n1 + n2 - n3)/2, Integers] && 
  (1 + n1 + n2 - n3)/2 <= 0]
```

So is this a bug of Mathematica?

Moreover, I also tried to evaluate a similar code.

```
Resolve[Exists[{n1, n2, n3}, {n1, n2, n3} \[Element] 
       NonNegativeIntegers, 
      1/2 (1 + n1 - n2 + n3) \[Element] NonPositiveIntegers]]
```

where `n2` and `n3` is swapped. But then the output is `True` both before and after `LaunchKernels[]`.

So what is the precise reason for this abnormal behavior?  Any idea how to solve it?

Note: If we use `Reduce` instead of `Resolve`, it will not help.

Comment: Observed with `"12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"`. Most likely a bug that you can report to Wolfram (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106227/how-to-report-a-bug-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolve does not have an algorithm for solving quantifier elimination problems involving Element[expr, Integers] conditions, where expr is not a variable. It chooses to replace the condition with equation Sin[Pi*expr]==0 (which is not the best choice here, see below), and then tries to solve the resulting problem using heuristics recursively calling Reduce. Whether a heuristic succeeds may depend on the exact format of the result returned by a recursive call to Reduce. Launching parallel kernels enables a recursive call to Reduce to use a parallel method, which produces an equivalent, but different, result than the non-parallel method. This different form of the result happens to be less useful for the calling heuristic, and hence the Resolve call fails.

The problem can be formulated using a congruence equation. With this formulation Resolve uses a much more efficient algorithm that does not make recursive Reduce calls and hence does not depend on the presence of parallel kernels.

```
In[2]:= Resolve[Exists[{n1, n2, n3}, {n1, n2, n3} \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers , (1 + n1 + n2 - n3)<=0 && Mod[1 + n1 + n2 - n3, 2]==0]]//Timing                

Out[2]= {0.010799, True}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precise answer. I tried to check (out of curiosity) if `Divisible[1 + n1 + n2 - n3, 2]` instead of `Mod[1 + n1 + n2 - n3, 2]==0` works or not. But it does not work and cannot give the output `True`. Do you know why this happens? Because `Divisible[]` and `Mod[]==0` are equivalent statements.

Comment: Resolve works only with equations, inequalities, and Element statements. It does not understand conditions expressed in other ways.