# Kernel quits upon computing RegionIntersection

Tags: regions, crash, intersection

Using 12.1.1.0 on MacOS BigSur I observe quitting Mathematica kernels when evaluating RegionIntersections on two regions that apparently only touch.

Example for Regions that cause the Kernel to quit without throwing error messages:

```
RegionIntersection[ 
 Polyhedron[{{-14.481838045552937`, -3.8913713702921195`, 
    13.743481930417099`}, {-13.387327710535084`, -4.686579676023987`, 
    14.579613424294676`}, {-13.592704266151834`, -3.145108820945274`, 
    14.801904645288225`}, {-12.786161768700419`, -4.476126018218702`, 
    13.92490718079964`}, {-12.982315767496441`, -3.0038758320024415`, 
    14.137216281827229`}, {-13.831522463803132`, -3.716627016121334`, 
    13.126322670747593`}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 3, 2}, {3, 5,
     6, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 6}}], 
 Cuboid[{-13.2`, -6.`, 14.375`}, {-10.8`, -3.5999999999999996`, 
   15.625`}]]
```

These are the regions:

[image: Regions that cause RegionIntersection to crash]

When I only slightly change the coordinates to get regions that either overlap or do not overlap at all, I get the intersection polyhedron or the empty region indicator instead.

These are the regions that do overlap

```
RegionIntersection[ 
 Polyhedron[{{-14.481838045552937`, -3.8913713702921195`, 
    13.743481930417099`}, {-13.387327710535084`, -4.686579676023987`, 
    14.579613424294676`}, {-13.592704266151834`, -3.145108820945274`, 
    14.801904645288225`}, {-12.786161768700419`, -4.476126018218702`, 
    13.92490718079964`}, {-12.982315767496441`, -3.0038758320024415`, 
    14.137216281827229`}, {-13.831522463803132`, -3.716627016121334`, 
    13.126322670747593`}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 3, 2}, {3, 5,
     6, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 6}}], 
 Cuboid[{-13.25`, -6.`, 14.375`}, {-10.75`, -3.5999999999999996`, 
   15.625`}]]
```

with the corresponding output:

[image: RegionIntersection output when having regions with overlap]

and the corresponding 3D graphics:

[image: overlapping regions]

These are the regions that do not overlap

```
RegionIntersection[ 
 Polyhedron[{{-14.481838045552937`, -3.8913713702921195`, 
    13.743481930417099`}, {-13.387327710535084`, -4.686579676023987`, 
    14.579613424294676`}, {-13.592704266151834`, -3.145108820945274`, 
    14.801904645288225`}, {-12.786161768700419`, -4.476126018218702`, 
    13.92490718079964`}, {-12.982315767496441`, -3.0038758320024415`, 
    14.137216281827229`}, {-13.831522463803132`, -3.716627016121334`, 
    13.126322670747593`}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 3, 2}, {3, 5,
     6, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 6}}], 
 Cuboid[{-13.15`, -6.`, 14.375`}, {-10.85`, -3.5999999999999996`, 
   15.625`}]]
```

The output here is EmptyRegion, and the corresponding 3D graphics is:

[image: 3D regions that do not overlap]

Comment: Post `Input` Mathematica code instead `Output` ?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. It is a good question, but it requires some editing.

Comment: The problem is trying to do a subtle calculation using machine precision. `Rationalize` the numeric values prior to calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction of the editing @Syed! At the beginning it looked good for me in the preview, but then when I posted it, the images were gone. Was the first time I posted something. Hopefully next time I manage without syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks to @MarcoB for the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @bobhanlon . I tried it, but with out success. Although, It would be helpful if a message was issued with this hint, instead producing a quitting kernel. Triggered by your comment, I tried to reduce the precision with `Round[]` (as RegionIntersection has no option for modifying this). This at least prevents the kernel from quitting. It does not evaluate the command, but I can catch this case with `Head[]` or similar.  Fortunately, I can go ahead with rather low precision, so this work-around does the job for me.

Comment: Oh, yes, just saw now that it was done by him. Thanks a lot for the editing, @marcob .

Comment: @Christophlerche You are very welcome.

Comment: A kernel crash like this represents a bug, and cannot be fixed by the people who visit this site.  It can only be fixed by Wolfram Research, and they will only fix it if someone reports it to them.  See [How to report a bug in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106227/9490)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @JasonB . Until now, I was only suspecting it could be a bug, but I was not sure. I will report to Mathematica as indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples with v12.1.1 using exact values rather than machine precision

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

rgn1 = Polyhedron[{{-14.481838045552937`, -3.8913713702921195`, 
      13.743481930417099`}, {-13.387327710535084`, -4.686579676023987`, 
      14.579613424294676`}, {-13.592704266151834`, -3.145108820945274`, 
      14.801904645288225`}, {-12.786161768700419`, -4.476126018218702`, 
      13.92490718079964`}, {-12.982315767496441`, -3.0038758320024415`, 
      14.137216281827229`}, {-13.831522463803132`, -3.716627016121334`, 
      13.126322670747593`}} // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 3, 2}, {3, 5, 6, 
     1}, {4, 2, 1, 6}}];

rgn2 = Cuboid @@ 
   Rationalize[{{-13.2`, -6.`, 14.375`}, {-10.8`, -3.5999999999999996`, 
      15.625`}}, 0];

rgn3 = RegionIntersection[rgn1, rgn2];

Volume[rgn3]

(* 3.91504*10^-8 *)

rgn4 = Cuboid @@ 
   Rationalize[{{-13.25`, -6.`, 14.375`}, {-10.75`, -3.5999999999999996`, 
      15.625`}}, 0];

rgn5 = RegionIntersection[rgn1, rgn4];

Volume[rgn5]

(* 0.00139939 *)
```

Comment: Thanks @bobhanlon . I was not aware of the second argument for `Rationalise[]`. This did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is another combination of regions with similar problems, and I'm not able to fix it with `Rationalise[]`. The description is in the Answer below, since characters for comment are too limited.

Answer (score 1):

I observe a very similar behaviour with the following two regions:

[image: Graphics3D of the corresponding regions]

When I try to run RegionIntersection on these regions, the computation takes more than 30 minutes. (I quit the kernel after this time, since for all other region pairs that I need to compute, the computations takes much less than a second). This is the corresponding command:

```
RegionIntersection[ 
 Cuboid[Rationalize[{-15.599999999999998`, 3.5999999999999996`, 
    13.125`}, 0], Rationalize[{-13.2`, 6.`, 14.375`}, 0]], 
 Polyhedron[
  Rationalize[{{-12.506721429921425`, 3.9624773092852443`, 
     15.656022698345078`}, {-13.443519981142686`, 4.706251231025362`, 
     14.640810221789032`}, {-13.649758588935882`, 3.158310171489477`, 
     14.864034492956131`}, {-12.837481483332462`, 4.494091809209582`, 
     13.980797468731524`}, {-13.034422783855483`, 3.0159324642645027`,
      14.193958713089975`}, {-11.942914132535591`, 3.783847471304209`,
      14.950243818178507`}}, 
   0], {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 3, 2}, {3, 5, 6, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 
    6}}]]
```

Now, when I change the order of the Polyhedron and the Cuboid, I get an output, i.e. the kernel does not hang or stuck in the computation, but I don't get the desired result. Instead, I get:

[image: The output when changing the order of arguments for RegionIntersection]

The command that produces this output is:

```
RegionIntersection[
 Polyhedron[
  Rationalize[{{-12.506721429921425`, 3.9624773092852443`, 
     15.656022698345078`}, {-13.443519981142686`, 4.706251231025362`, 
     14.640810221789032`}, {-13.649758588935882`, 3.158310171489477`, 
     14.864034492956131`}, {-12.837481483332462`, 4.494091809209582`, 
     13.980797468731524`}, {-13.034422783855483`, 3.0159324642645027`,
      14.193958713089975`}, {-11.942914132535591`, 3.783847471304209`,
      14.950243818178507`}}, 
   0], {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 3, 2}, {3, 5, 6, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 
    6}}], Cuboid[
  Rationalize[{-15.599999999999998`, 3.5999999999999996`, 13.125`}, 
   0], Rationalize[{-13.2`, 6.`, 14.375`}, 0]]]
```