# Applying a `GeometricTransformation` to an `AxisObject` along an `InfiniteLine`

Tags: graphics, geometric-transform

I want to take a list of graphics primitives and draw them on top of another set of graphics primitives, using a child coordinate system. To do this, I'm using a `GeometricTransformation` to map the child coordinates to the parent coordinates, and then drawing everything with a single call to `Graphics`. Example:

```
Graphics[{
    Circle[],
    GeometricTransformation[{
        AxisObject[Line[{{-1,0},{1,0}}],{-1,1}],
        AxisObject[Line[{{0,-1},{0,1}}],{-1,1}],
        Rectangle[]
        },
        {{{2/5,0},{0,2/5}},{3/5,3/10}}
    ]
    },
    Axes->True
]
```

[image: 1]

But, when I use `InfiniteLine` instead of `Line`, all of the tick marks and labels disappear, and I just get a line instead of an axis:

[image: 2]

With no `GeometricTransformation`, the axes display properly, even when using `InfiniteLine`:

```
Graphics[{
    AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{-1,0},{1,0}}],{-1,1}],
    AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0,-1},{0,1}}],{-1,1}],
    Rectangle[]
}, PlotRange -> {{-0.5,1.5},{-0.5,1.5}}]
```

[image: 3]

Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly? It looks like a bug to me, but I can't be certain. I just updated to the latest version (13.2.1) and get the same behaviour.

Comment: When in doubt, [report it a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106232/9490).